# Query INSERT com condição WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Como posso fazer um insert com uma condição where?

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
INSERT INTO `registro`(`id`, `username`)

values

('','USER_1'),
('','USER_2'),
('','USER_3')
```

Ele vai adicionar um novo usuário na tabela registro. Só que eu preciso que ele verifique se esse usuário já existe no DB, se já existir ele não deve inserir. Essa verificação deve ser feita apenas para a coluna `username`.

Eu li em alguns lugares que o INSERT não aceita o WHERE, nesse caso como deveria ser feito?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No SQL da pra fazer assim

```
  INSERT INTO pessoa (id, nome, sexo, datanascimento, cpf) 
       SELECT 227,'FULANDO DE TAL','F','1999-09-09', '999.999.999-9'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pessoa WHERE id = 227);
```

Comment: Estava exatamente escrevendo esta resposta. A mais rápida leva.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino hahahahhaa.

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres E como fazer para mais de uma linha a ser inserida?

Comment: @Wendler o próprio `SELECT` cuidará disso.

Comment: Então, é que eu preciso incluir mais de um registro no mesmo comando, ai devo repetir a query inteira, ou só o `SELECT`?

Comment: Coloque a parte do seu código pra gente poder entender melhor sua necessidade.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta ali, nesse caso ele vai inserir 3 registros.

Comment: Se você precisa fazer a verificação em todos os values, é necessario passar todos eles pelo select, pois são valores diferentes e então o retorno poderá ser diferente também.

Comment: E como fazer isso, repetindo todo o SELECT? Desculpe, sou bem leigo no mysql.

Comment: Porque do 1, em SELECT 1, no WHERE NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 3):

O `Mysql` não suporta o `where` no `insert`, mas você pode utilizar `insert` com `select`

```
INSERT INTO Users(weight, desiredWeight) 
    SELECT weight, desiredWeight 
    FROM AnotherTable 
    WHERE id = 1
```

pode ter mais detalhes de como fazer [aqui](http://www.jrossetto.com.br/tutoriais/banco-de-dados/mysql/insert-com-select-na-mesma-query-mysql/)

ai consegui fazer algum filtro, caso a linha já exista e vc vai adicionar mais informação sugiro `update`

Answer (score 2):

Como @Renan já mencionou, não é permitido `WHERE` no  `INSERT`, então usar um `SELECT` como a reposta da @Danielle vai resolver no seu caso. Me parece que a chave da sua tabela é a coluna `id` e não `username`, mas se fosse validar o campo chave poderia usar `IGNORE` no seu comando.

Para ilustrar a quem tiver a mesma dúvida, mas a validação for no campo chave, você pode simples usar `INSERT IGNORE`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Nesse caso, será ignorado o comando caso viole a chave primária, ou seja, já exista, e a sintaxe seria a seguinte no seu exemplo:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `registro`(`id`, `username`)
values
('','USER')
```

Comment: Não, a chave primária é a coluna `id`, mas eu preciso que ele verifique a coluna `username`.

Comment: Imaginei, então o `insert` com `select` deve ser a melhor opção pra você, mas deixo registrado aqui caso alguém tenha um cenário diferente, e deseje usar o `ignore`

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pela resposta. :)

Comment: você sabe alguma forma de utilizar o `insert` com `select`, porém para vários `values`? Eu atualizei a pergunta para uma melhor exemplificação.

Comment: com um único comando acho que não vai ser possível... a solução mais prática seria inserir numa tabela temporária, depois inserir na tabela *registro* somente os valores que não existirem. Ai da pra fazer o insert com select, ou seja, dois comandos insert

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisei a mesma coisa e como não vi uma solução criei a minha no MySQL
Tenho uma tabela de relacionamento N-N mas alguns registros não estavam nela
Fiz uma consulta nas 2 tabelas BASE_A e BASE_B forçando um produto cartesiano

```
    SELECT BASE_A.ID_A, BASE_B.ID_B FROM BASE_A, BASE_B
```

(Sem colocar no join ou WHERE  com a tabela N-N)

E depois fiz o where com o NOT IN na tabela que deveria ter os dados

```
    select BASE_A.ID_A, BASE_B.ID_B 
    FROM BASE_A, BASE_B 
    where (BASE_A.ID_A, BASE_B.ID_B) not in (
    select ID_A,ID_B from TABELA_N_N )
```

E funcionou como o esperado

Answer (score -2):

opa! desculpe se minha resposta não  estiver certa, pois tenho pouco conhecimento no mysql e não sei a sintaxe correta mas acho que seria mais facil fazer o select antes do insert, ai é so verificar se retorou alguma coisa do select. tipo.

```
var $verifica (int 2)
$verifica = select count registro where  username = USER_1

if( $verifica >0)
    INSERT INTO `registro`(`id`, `username`)values('','USER_1');
else
   return = "usuario ja existe!";
endif
```

como ja falei antes, não sei a sintax correta para o mysql mas essa seria uma logica mais simples para o caso em questão

Comment: Por favor, não use tanto as respostas, como as perguntas, para cumprimentar, se desculpar, conversar ou falar de você. O objetivo aqui da plataforma é veicular por meio de ferramentas de automação o conhecimento, aqui produzido, ao maior número de pessoa no planeta, seja hoje, seja no futuro. Escreva de forma pragmática, concentre-se no conteúdo técnico pois da forma que está escrita a resposta irá gerar ruído a respeito do assunto dentro das engines de IA/ML. Mais informações veja em [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)