# INSERT com cláusula SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Encontrei no [SOpt uma resposta para o mesmo caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290775/query-insert-com-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-where) que o meu, mas algo inesperado acontece pois isso é novidade para mim, a instrução SQL abaixo retorna um erro ao ser executada.

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO 
    `usuario_referencia`
(
`ade_user`,
`ade_ticket`,
`ade_status`
)
SELECT 
'CB15-1901',
'102030',
'A'
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 
        1 
    FROM 
        `usuario_referencia` 
    WHERE 
        `ade_user` = '102030' 
    AND 
        `ade_user` = 'CB15-1901'
    )
";
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ' at line 12

A dúvida é, no MariaDB o uso de SELECT 1 é possível? se não é isso, o que deve ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu `select` está faltando o `from`. Como está gerando dados que não estão numa tabela, pode usar o `FROM DUAL`

```
SELECT 
'CB15-1901',
'102030',
'A'
FROM DUAL
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 
        1 
    FROM 
        `usuario_referencia` 
    WHERE 
        `ade_user` = '102030' 
    AND 
        `ade_user` = 'CB15-1901'
    )
```

`DUAL` é um nome de tabela fictício, e assim como no `Oracle` é usado num `SELECT` que não tem resultados de uma tabela específica, e é necessário pois o `FROM` é obrigatório para o `select`.

Veja aqui o DUAL funcionando: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/96366)

Veja a documentação aqui: [MYSQL SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) e [MARIADB DUAL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dual/)

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pelas referências.